# Ghc can't infer the use of mtl instances despite entries in the function context

Tags: haskell, typeclass, monad-transformers

I have an API that helps extract values from a large chain of records. Here is one of the functions definitions. Other examples, use the logging typeclass feature.

```hs
-- |
-- Unifying filter for FieldValues
-- The "failed" search returns a null set.
--
filterValues, filterQualReqValues
  :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
  => FieldValues -> FieldValues
  -> m FieldValues
filterValues (TxtSet s) (TxtSet vs)   = pure . TxtSet  $ Set.intersection s vs
filterValues (IntSet s) (IntSet vs)   = pure . IntSet  $ Set.intersection s vs
filterValues (SpanSet s) (SpanSet vs) = pure . SpanSet $ Set.intersection s vs
filterValues s _                      = throw $ TypeException (Just . pack $ show s)
filterQualReqValues = filterValues
```

In my attempts to use the API...

```hs
fetchQualities :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
               => [GqlInput.QualityReqInput] -> Model.Qualities
               -> m (Maybe Model.ReqQualities)
fetchQualities requests etl = 
  let
      -- wrap, process using shared logic, unwrap
      (subSetReqs, fullSetReqs) = mapTuple (catMaybes . (fmap unWrapQual))
                                $ ppSubsetting (Qual <$> requests)

      fullSetReqs' :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
                   => m [(Model.QualName, Maybe Model.QualValues)]
      fullSetReqs' = catMaybes <$> traverse (`fetchFullSet` etl) fullSetReqs

      subSetReqs' :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
                  => m [(Model.QualName, Maybe Model.QualValues)]
      subSetReqs' = catMaybes <$> traverse (`fetchSubset` etl) subSetReqs

      result :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
             => m Model.ReqQualities
      result = (<>) <$> (Model.fromListReqQualities <$> subSetReqs') -- <<< subSetReqs' error
               <*> Model.fromListReqQualities <$> fullSetReqs'
   in
      do
        result' :: Model.ReqQualities <- result
        if Model.null result' then pure Nothing
                              else pure $ Just result'

   where

    fetchSubset :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
                => GqlInput.QualityReqInput
                -> Model.Qualities
                -> m (Maybe (Model.QualName, Maybe Model.QualValues))

    fetchSubset req etl' = do
      -- process key
      reqWithValues <- getEtlFragment req etl' :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m) => m (Maybe (Model.QualName, Model.QualValues))
      case reqWithValues of
        Nothing -> pure Nothing
        Just (key, etlValues) -> do
          -- process values
          let valuesReq  = GqlInput.qualityValues req  -- :: Maybe GqlInput.QualValuesInput
          case valuesReq of
            Nothing         -> pure $ Just (key, Nothing)
            Just valuesReq' -> do
              let valuesReq'' = fromInputReqQualValues valuesReq'
              values <- filterQualReqValues valuesReq'' etlValues
              if Model.null values then pure Nothing
                                   else pure $ Just (key, Just values)


    fetchFullSet :: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
                 => GqlInput.QualityReqInput
                 -> Model.Qualities
                 -> m (Maybe (Model.QualName, Maybe Model.QualValues))
    fetchFullSet req etl' = do
      let reqName = getQualName req
      case reqName of
         Nothing   -> pure Nothing        -- no key in the request
         Just name -> do
            key <- lookupQualityKey (Model.mkQualKey name) etl'
            pure ((,Nothing) <$> key)       -- key determines return
```

I get an error

```hs
• Could not deduce (MonadLogger
                          ((->) [(Model.ETL.Key.QualKey, Maybe Model.QualValues)]))
        arising from a use of ‘subSetReqs'’
      from the context: (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m)
        bound by the type signature for:
                   fetchQualities :: forall (m :: * -> *).
                                     (MonadLogger m, MonadThrow m) =>
                                     [GqlInput.QualityReqInput]
                                     -> Model.Qualities -> m (Maybe Model.ReqQualities)
        at src/Api/GQL/Input/SubRequest.hs:(143,1)-(145,46)
```

Despite the insane amount of type annotations, and making sure none of them are actually blocking ghc from inferring something, I cannot find my way out of this error.  What I can infer is that I am somehow creating/inferring a separate instance of `m`?

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

- E

Comment: The `m` in your signature is a different type variable than the `m` in the "outer" type function, so that fails.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Thank you. May you clarify; when you say "outer" type function, what are you referring to?  Also, if that is the case, what can I do to make sure ghc sees them as one in the same?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem To clarify: I have `ScopedTypeVariables` in my pragma.  In my understanding, the type variables should apply throughout the body of the definition... including what's in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a closer at the error message:

```
Could not deduce (MonadLogger
                  ((->) [(Model.ETL.Key.QualKey, Maybe Model.QualValues)]))
arising from a use of subSetReqs'
```

you see that GHC has decided that it needs a `MonadLogger` instance for a partial function application.  Specifically, it's trying to use the implicit reader monad instance for `(->) some_type` (which is odd) and expects that type to support logging (which is crazy).

This means you have a type error in your program.

It looks to me like you want, at the very least, to have some additional parenthesis in the line *following* the error:

```
<*> (Model.fromListReqQualities <$> fullSetReqs')
    ^                                           ^
    `---------------- add these ----------------'
```

Comment: Thank you! That was it.  This is my first foray into more robust use of `mtl` and `transformers`.  Your comment seemed to hint at what I feel is the case... I've made this too complex.  Are there any obvious design flaws that you're seeing?

Comment: If you mean my saying "at the very least", I only meant that I had no idea if that alone would be sufficient to fix the problem.  It wasn't a larger criticism of the design or the style, which seem fine from what little I can see.  You probably don't need all the "internal" type signatures any more; I'd be surprised if any of them can't be inferred, and they probably don't add much to clarify the code, so removing them might help de-clutter.  If you can post a self-contained example to [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you might get some useful feedback.

Comment: Perfect.  Thank you.